# GPS module take time

Tags: networking, gps, sensors, tinyos, nesc

how much GPS module take time to get the gps infromation,
if i use 420cc sensor board attached to this gps module [uBlox LEA-4A](http://www.u-blox.com/)  .

i use Iris mote.

Comment: You mean the time before you get a first fix, or the latency?

Comment: yes, how much time take to read gps information

Comment: why dont you look at the homepage of uBlox and read the data sheet, search for TTF: Time to first fix.

Answer (score 1):

The data sheets usualy state a Time to First fix of 30-40s having a good antenna.
But the first time the GPS device is enabled it will need 10 - 15 minutes.
Both times valuid when having free view to sky

Answer (score 0):

When a GPS receiver is switched on, it needs to get the data from at least three GPS satellites before it can give its position. Generally this takes about a minute, but it might take longer if the receiver is far from where it was last used or it's been off for a very long time.